# Uber GET requests 403

Tags: uber-api

I am trying

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/<REQUEST_ID>"
```

and response is 403

```
{"message":"Forbidden","code":"forbidden"}
```

But the https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/scopes says that

> The good news is you currently have access to these scopes when authorizing your own account or those of the developer accounts you list in your application dashboard (Limited Access). This allows you to start building an app immediately.

I've got token via OAuth using my own account

1. I've set param "scope=request" to `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize`
2. And I've set "scope=request" when did `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token`

Also I've trying to do request to `https://sandbox-api.uber.com`, it responds

```
{ "message": "cannot find trip", "code": "not_found" }
```

But I think it's ok, because sandbox doesn't contain my own account data, right?

Where is my fault could be?

Comment: You can only access ride requests originating from your app. In this case, I think you are not passing the correct request id or it is a ride request from a different app.

Comment: _it is a ride request from a different app_ does it mean that I have no rights to getting requests from my uber history?

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it. Thank you @DustinWhittle :)

Comment: You can access the past trips from the /history endpoint, but not use /requests/current (unless ride request created from your app).